# Java FileChannel missing unmap ( RAM consequences ? )

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, mmap

I'm creating/using memory mapped files in FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE mode in my application. Thoses files are created and deleted throughout the life cycle of the application.

As the GC does not necessarly free the direct buffers to _ unmap _ the underlying OS buffers I'm wondering what are the consequences in the OS and more specifically about the RAM usage.

I understand about the "Virtual Memory" of the process still being polluted by unecessary mappings but what are the consequences on the actual RAM usage (I guess buffers in "Resident Memory" are flushed over time).

It seems the process can OOM (out-of-memory) at OS level (crash JVM) - not Java OOM (out-of-memory) (still plenty of space in the heap).

I'm on a Linux 64bits (3.13.0-68-generic / Ubuntu) box and using the Oracle JRE 1.8.0_66-b17.

Comment: The consequence is that you will use more and more RAM, of course. You shouldn't use this for lots of files, only for a single file or so that is going to stay open for long periods. The speed advantage is only around 20%.

Comment: "It seems the process can OOM at OS level" is that a theory or did you manage to crash it? I would actually be surprised if a few (hundred) mappings would cause much problems. All that the OS needs to keep track of is which address space belongs to a file. And only pieces of files that are actually touched are needed to be buffered in physical RAM. Swapping ram back to disk is a thing this piece of the system does all of the time so it should be very efficient at quickly flushing buffers back to disk and reusing them for more important things.

Comment: @EJP : RAM for which purpose?

Comment: @MarcPolizzi For the purpose you are describing in your question, of course. Strange thing to ask.

Comment: @EJP: sure I'm using more RAM, but my question is about what kind of data structure would be kept, its estimated size, etc...

Comment: The data structure is a byte array the size of the mapping, mapped to the file contents, plus the tiny overhead of the `MappedByteBuffer.`

Answer (score 1):

Address space is a resource that you can run out of independently (somewhat) of usable memory.

With disk-backed file mappings, you only consume as much memory as you have page cache (cached reads and dirty pages awaiting write).  But the reserved address space is the size of the whole mapping.

You also consume file handles, and likely run out of those first.

Java does `munmap` mappings when they are GCed -- however, that means that it happens on the GC's schedule not yours.  This usually is okay, as long as it releases address space quicker than you allocate it.  But much like file descriptors or any other finite resource, you definitely can run out.

With 64 bits, that'd take a while.  It's much more of an issue on 32 bit systems.

There's lots of calls for improved control of mappings, since relying on finalizers isn't great.  But it's really hard to do better without compromising performance or security.  [To quote Sun's evaluation of the problem](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724038)

> There is no unmap() method on mapped byte buffers because there is no known
>   technique for providing one without running into insurmountable security and
>   performance issues.

Comment: I'm on a 64bits system so the address space is ok. File handles are fine it seems as well. But thanks for your input.

Comment: file handles can be closed without closing the mapping, so at least that part should not be an issue